# SecItemCopyMatching always returns 'does not appear to be a valid keychain item' for a stored EC key

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

I have a function that creates a new key in the iOS keychain using this method:

```
func initialize(_ keyTag: String) throws -> DeviceBindingParameters {
    let tag = keyTag.data(using: .utf8)!
    let attributes: [String: Any] =
            [kSecAttrKeyType       as String: kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom,
             kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String: 256,
             kSecPrivateKeyAttrs   as String: [
                kSecAttrIsPermanent    as String: true,
                kSecAttrLabel          as String: tag,
                kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: tag
             ]
            ]

    ... other stuff
}
```

And then there is also a function which checks if this key is present or not:

```
open func doesKeyExist(_ keyTag: String) -> Bool {
    let tag = keyTag.data(using: .utf8)!
    let query: [String: Any] = [
            kSecClass as String : kSecAttrKeyType,
            kSecAttrLabel as String : tag,
            kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: tag,
            kSecAttrKeyType as String: kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom,
            kSecReturnRef as String: true
    ]
        
    var item: CFTypeRef?
    let status = SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, &item)
    let errorDescription = SecCopyErrorMessageString(status,nil)
    print(errorDescription)
    return status == noErr
}
```

And I call this method simply one after the other (for quick testing I'm calling this from `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    do {
        try crypto.initialize("rohan-key")
        let keyStatus = try crypto.doesKeyExist("rohan-key")
            print("Key status: \(keyStatus)")
    } catch {
        print("errors")
    }
```

And I always get this output:

```
Optional(The specified item does not appear to be a valid keychain item.)
Key status: false
```

The first message is printed from calling the `SecCopyErrorMessageString` on the status of `SecItemCopyMatching`. Furthermore, I am very sure that the key generation is working because I use the key to sign a canonical message, send it over the wire and then verify that signature on a Java-based backend - so those parts are completely fine. I am just not sure why the item does not persist in the keystore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a minor mistake at `kSecClass as String : kSecAttrKeyType`. `kSecAttrKeyType` is a key indicating the type of the key (`kSecAttrKeyTypeEC`/`kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom`/`kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA`). So you should pass the correct `kSecClass` which for you should be `kSecClassKey`.

I'd like to point out that the output of the `SecCopyErrorMessageString` is a bit bad every now and then. Always try to print the `OSStatus` as well and use that on [OSStatus](https://www.osstatus.com). Which in this case would not have given you greatest hits, as it would've returned -50. But the combination of the two identifies them uniquely enough to define it as `errSecNoSuchClass` [found here](https://www.osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=-50).

Comment: Yup. This seemed to be it, and thanks for the link to osstatus - that's massively helpful!